Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at seo-uzmani:539:1Understand this errorAI
I am getting a specific error on only 1 page of our site. We have researched this error everywhere but no one is giving a clear answer. What could be the reason why we are getting this error on only 1 single page?
Page : turksem.com/seo-uzmani
Thank you for your help.

This question appears to be off-topic because it is about web development which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their FAQ before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does not meet their guidelines.
